# How to prove n <= n + S m in coq?

Tags: coq

I have the last subgoal to prove a theorem.
and it's:

```
1 subgoal
b, d : nat
H : 0 <= b
H0 : 0 <= d
m : nat
H1 : 0 <= m
H2 : S m = d
______________________________________(1/1)
b <= b + S m
```

I think I need an assumption like n <= n + Sm for this.
Anyone can help me out?? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lia` tactic, which stands for "Linear Integer Arithmetic", can solve this and many similar goals. E.g.:

```
Require Import Lia.

Goal forall b m, b <= b + S m.
Proof. intros. lia. Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is lemma `le_plus_l` of the standard library.
It might be a good time for you to get familiar with the `Search` command. It is very useful to find theorems, and quite powerful once you get the hand of it. Here for instance I simply used `Search (?x <= ?x + _)` and got exactly the thing you were looking for.